# Eclipse Project Strange Icons Importing Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a **Maven** project on one computer and uploaded it to *Github*.

To get it on my other computer I cloned it using *Github for Windows* and used the *Import existing Maven project* option in **Eclipse**.
My project seems fine, but it has these weird yellow icons on all my files.

Any particular reason for these? Can I remove them?

Comment: can you goto window > view > problems and post the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the icons you are talking about...

[image]

These are egit icons for git projects and each of those icons on a file means that the file is tracked.

You can disable it on the project by right clicking on the project, then Team->Disconnect